# Is there a way to successfully implement multiprocessing with Keras neural networks for reinforcement learning?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, multiprocessing, reinforcement-learning

Upon exploring actor-critic, I have been trying to speed up my program using multiprocessing. However, the code runs fine until the point where I start using processes. The code starts, but then never stops at one episode (keeps running, showing looping behavior). I have been searching for possible errors, and as far as I am concerned, the fault is due to each process calling its sub-process (?). That being said, I really want to find out how to fix the multiprocessing part so that my program will run, so I would really appreciate any help.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import gym
import time
import random
import multiprocessing as mp

from keras.layers import Reshape, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from collections import deque

# Configuration parameters for the whole setup
gamma = 1  # Discount factor for past rewards
max_steps_per_episode = 2000
env = gym.make("Taxi-v3").env  # Create the environment
eps = 1e-6

num_inputs = 1
num_actions = 6
num_hidden = 64

simulated_epsilon = 0

# Actor Policy Network
inputs_1 = layers.Input(shape=(num_inputs,))
embed = layers.Embedding(500, 10, input_length=num_inputs)(inputs_1)
reshape = layers.Reshape((10 * num_inputs, ))(embed)
common = layers.Dense(num_hidden * 2, activation="relu")(reshape)
common = layers.Dense(num_hidden, activation="relu")(common)
action = layers.Dense(num_actions, activation="softmax")(common)

model_1 = keras.Model(inputs=inputs_1, outputs=action)

# Critic Reward Network
inputs_2 = layers.Input(shape=(num_inputs,))
embed_2 = layers.Embedding(500, 10, input_length=num_inputs)(inputs_2)
reshape_2 = layers.Reshape((10, ))(embed_2)
common_2 = layers.Dense(num_hidden * 2, activation="relu")(reshape_2)
common_2 = layers.Dense(num_hidden, activation="relu")(common_2)
critic = layers.Dense(1)(common_2)

model_2 = keras.Model(inputs=inputs_2, outputs=critic)

# Optimizer and Loss Function
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-4)
huber_loss = keras.losses.Huber()
action_probs_history = []
critic_value_history = []
rewards_history = []
running_reward = 0
episode_count = 0

under_20 = 0

model_2.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-4), loss=huber_loss)

def worker(number, env, actor, critic):
  optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-4)
  huber_loss = keras.losses.Huber()
  action_probs_history = []
  critic_value_history = []
  rewards_history = []
  running_reward = 0
  episode_count = 0
  under_20 = 0
  
  while True:  # Run until solved
    state = env.reset()
    episode_reward = 0
    penalties = 0
    drop = 0
    print("Episode {} begins ({})".format(episode_count, number))
    env.render()
    start = time.time()

    time_solve = 0

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape_1, tf.GradientTape() as tape_2:
    #with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        #while True:
        for _ in range(1, max_steps_per_episode + 1):
            #env.render()  # Adding this line would show the attempts
            # of the agent in a pop up window.

            state = tf.convert_to_tensor(state)
            state = tf.expand_dims(state, 0)

            # Predict action probabilities and estimated future rewards
            # from environment state
            action_probs = actor(state)
            critic_value = critic(state)
            critic_value_history.append((state, critic_value[0, 0]))

            # Choose action
            action = np.random.choice(num_actions, p=np.squeeze(action_probs))
            action_probs_history.append(tf.math.log(action_probs[0, action])) # action_probs stores log of probs of action

            #if timestep == 1:
            #  print("{}: {}".format(state, action_probs))
            #  print("{}: {}".format(state, action))

            # Apply the sampled action in our environment
            state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            rewards_history.append(reward)
            episode_reward += reward
            time_solve += 1

            if reward == -10:
              penalties += 1
            
            elif reward == 20:
              drop += 1

            if done:
                break
        
        # Update running reward to check condition for solving
        running_reward = (running_reward * (episode_count) + episode_reward) / (episode_count + 1)

        # Calculate expected value from rewards
        # - At each timestep what was the total reward received after that timestep
        # - Rewards in the past are discounted by multiplying them with gamma
        # - These are the labels for our critic
        returns = deque(maxlen=3500)
        discounted_sum = 0
        for r in rewards_history[::-1]:
            discounted_sum = r + gamma * discounted_sum
            returns.appendleft(discounted_sum)

        # Normalize
        #returns = np.array(returns)
        returns = (returns - np.mean(returns)) / (np.std(returns) + eps)
        #returns = returns.tolist()

        # Calculating loss values to update our network
        history = zip(action_probs_history, critic_value_history, returns)
        loss_value_actor = 0
        loss_value_critic = 0
        for log_prob, value, ret in history:
            diff = ret - value[1]
            loss_value_actor += -log_prob * diff
            loss_value_critic += huber_loss(tf.expand_dims(value[1], 0), tf.expand_dims(ret, 0))


        # Backpropagation
        #loss_value_actor /= time_solve
        #loss_value_critic /= time_solve
        
        if episode_count % 2 == 1:
          grads_1 = tape_1.gradient(loss_value_actor, model_1.trainable_variables)
          optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads_1, model_1.trainable_variables))
        
        grads_2 = tape_2.gradient(loss_value_critic, model_2.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads_2, model_2.trainable_variables))

        # Clear the loss and reward history
        action_probs_history.clear()
        critic_value_history.clear()
        rewards_history.clear()

        # Copy params
        actor.set_weights(model_1.get_weights())
        critic.set_weights(model_2.get_weights())

    # Log details
    end = time.time()
    episode_count += 1
    if episode_count % 1 == 0:
        env.render()
        template = "average reward: {:.2f}"
        print(template.format(running_reward, episode_count))
        print("episode reward: {}".format(episode_reward))
        print("Steps taken: {}".format(time_solve))
        print("Penalties incurred: {}".format(penalties))
        print("Passengers dropped off: {}".format(drop))
        print("Time taken: {}".format(end - start))
        print()

    if running_reward > -50:  # Condition to consider the task solved
        under_20 += 1
    
    if under_20 > 5:
        print("Solved at episode {} !".format(episode_count))
        break

num_processes = 5

if __name__ == "__main__":
  mp.freeze_support()
  envs = []
  processes = []
  actors = []
  critics = []

  for i in range(num_processes):
    envs.append(gym.make("Taxi-v3").env)
  
  for i in range(num_processes):
    t = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(i, envs[i], model_1, model_2))
    t.start()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    processes.append(t)
  
  for process in processes:
    process.join()
  
  for process in processes:
    process.terminate()
```